# Is segwit2x really called off?

Tags: consensus, segwit2x

Is the segwit2x called off for sure for now?

I see there is still 53.9% intention as of 15th Nov for Segwit2x ([Source](https://coin.dance/blocks/segwit2x))

I know this is not sure that it is called off forever, but I just want to know whether it will happen anytime soon as the NYA agreement of making segwit2x on block 494784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not sure whether it's completely off the table, but they have indeed called it off for now:

"Segwit2x hardfork has been called off! Common sense prevails"

You can see some things in this article: https://www.coindesk.com/relief-disbelief-bitcoin-reacts-sudden-2x-suspension/

And this is the message they sent out: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-segwit2x/2017-November/000685.html

Cheers,

David